# PySpark: Merging two dataframes if one condition achieved from a two conditions

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Q: Is there is any way to merge two dataframes if one condition achieved from a two conditions?

For example, I have two Dataframes:

```
DF1

 name           Exam
 Ahmad          100
 Ahmad          95
 Ahmad          90
 Emma           80
 Emma           85
```

the second dataframe

```
DF2

 name       math     phy.   prev._Rank
 Ahmad      100      90     2
 Emma       80       85     1
```

I want the resulting DF as follows:

```
NEW DF

name     Exam      math     phy.    Prev._Rank
 Ahmad   100       100      90      2
 Ahmad   95        null     null    2
 Ahmad   90        100      90      2
 Emma    80        80       85      1
 Emma    85        80       85      1
```

Comment: It looks like to left join, but apparently you messed up with the expected result so I don't see any logic there...

Comment: Can you add more detail on what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I want to join the two DFs if there is value in the math or phy. columns matches with the value in the  Exam column for the same student with preserving other values doesn't exist in DF2   and if is possible to give the prev._rank for the same student as shown in row 2 it will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF1=spark.createDataFrame([('Ahmad','100'),('Ahmad','95'),('Ahmad','90'),('Ahmad','50'),('Ahmad','51'),('Ahmad','54'),('Ahmad','53'),('Emma','52'),('Emma','85')],['namea','Exam'])

DF1=DF1.select('namea',DF1.Exam.cast('integer'))




DF1.show()

+-----+----+
|namea|Exam|
+-----+----+
|Ahmad| 100|
|Ahmad|  95|
|Ahmad|  90|
|Ahmad|  50|
|Ahmad|  51|
|Ahmad|  54|
|Ahmad|  53|
| Emma|  52|
| Emma|  85|
+-----+----+

DF2=spark.createDataFrame([('Ahmad','100','90','2'),('Ahmad','50','54','3'),('Emma','52','85','1')],['name','math','phy','Prev_Rank'])
DF2=DF2.select('name',DF2.math.cast('integer'),DF2.phy.cast('integer'),'Prev_Rank')


DF2.show()

+-----+----+---+---------+
| name|math|phy|Prev_Rank|
+-----+----+---+---------+
|Ahmad| 100| 90|        2|
|Ahmad|  50| 54|        3|
| Emma|  52| 85|        1|
+-----+----+---+---------+
```

Solution

```
DF3=DF1.join(DF2,[DF1.namea==DF2.name,DF1.Exam==DF2.math],'leftouter')

DF3.show()

+-----+----+-----+----+----+---------+
|namea|Exam| name|math| phy|Prev_Rank|
+-----+----+-----+----+----+---------+
|Ahmad|  90| null|null|null|     null|
| Emma|  85| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  50|Ahmad|  50|  54|        3|
|Ahmad|  53| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  54| null|null|null|     null|
| Emma|  52| Emma|  52|  85|        1|
|Ahmad|  95| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad| 100|Ahmad| 100|  90|        2|
|Ahmad|  51| null|null|null|     null|
+-----+----+-----+----+----+---------+

DF4=DF1.join(DF2,[DF1.namea==DF2.name,DF1.Exam==DF2.phy],'leftouter').withColumnRenamed('name','name1').withColumnRenamed('math','math1').withColumnRenamed('phy','phy1').withColumnRenamed('Prev_Rank','Prev_Rank1')

DF4.show()

+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|namea|Exam|name1|math1|phy1|Prev_Rank1|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|Ahmad|  90|Ahmad|  100|  90|         2|
| Emma|  85| Emma|   52|  85|         1|
|Ahmad|  50| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  53| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  54|Ahmad|   50|  54|         3|
| Emma|  52| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  95| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad| 100| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  51| null| null|null|      null|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+

DF5=DF4.join(DF3,['namea','Exam'],'inner').orderBy(['namea','Exam'])

DF5.show()

+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----+---------+
|namea|Exam|name1|math1|phy1|Prev_Rank1| name|math| phy|Prev_Rank|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----+---------+
|Ahmad|  50| null| null|null|      null|Ahmad|  50|  54|        3|
|Ahmad|  51| null| null|null|      null| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  53| null| null|null|      null| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  54|Ahmad|   50|  54|         3| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  90|Ahmad|  100|  90|         2| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad|  95| null| null|null|      null| null|null|null|     null|
|Ahmad| 100| null| null|null|      null|Ahmad| 100|  90|        2|
| Emma|  52| null| null|null|      null| Emma|  52|  85|        1|
| Emma|  85| Emma|   52|  85|         1| null|null|null|     null|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+-----+----+----+---------+

DF6=DF5.withColumn("name1",coalesce(DF5.name1,DF5.name)).withColumn("math1",coalesce(DF5.math1,DF5.math)).withColumn("phy1",coalesce(DF5.phy1,DF5.phy)).withColumn("Prev_Rank1",coalesce(DF5.Prev_Rank1,DF5.Prev_Rank)).drop('name','math','phy','Prev_Rank')

DF6.show()

+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|namea|Exam|name1|math1|phy1|Prev_Rank1|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|Ahmad|  50|Ahmad|   50|  54|         3|
|Ahmad|  51| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  53| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad|  54|Ahmad|   50|  54|         3|
|Ahmad|  90|Ahmad|  100|  90|         2|
|Ahmad|  95| null| null|null|      null|
|Ahmad| 100|Ahmad|  100|  90|         2|
| Emma|  52| Emma|   52|  85|         1|
| Emma|  85| Emma|   52|  85|         1|
+-----+----+-----+-----+----+----------+

import sys
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
​

DF7=DF6.withColumn("Prev_Rank1", fn.last('Prev_Rank1', True).over(Window.partitionBy('namea').orderBy('Exam').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).drop('name1')


DF7.show()

+-----+----+-----+----+----------+
|namea|Exam|math1|phy1|Prev_Rank1|
+-----+----+-----+----+----------+
|Ahmad|  50|   50|  54|         3|
|Ahmad|  51| null|null|         3|
|Ahmad|  53| null|null|         3|
|Ahmad|  54|   50|  54|         3|
|Ahmad|  90|  100|  90|         2|
|Ahmad|  95| null|null|         2|
|Ahmad| 100|  100|  90|         2|
| Emma|  52|   52|  85|         1|
| Emma|  85|   52|  85|         1|
+-----+----+-----+----+----------+
```